# NSURL error - File does not exist

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfquery

I have a problem.

When I do `print("Video URL: \(self.videoUrl.description)")` i get this in the output:

```
Video URL: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/92BDA035-131C-4FD2-A176-25F77C1D295B/Documents/video.mp4
```

I am using this to upload the file to the server:

```
func uploadVideo(){
        let currentUploads = PFObject(className: "myClassOne")
        currentUploads.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil{
                //**Success saving, now save video.**//

                currentUploads["userFile"] = try! PFFile(name: "video.mp4", contentsAtPath: self.videoUrl.description)
                currentUploads.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if error == nil{
                        // Take user home
                        print("Successfully uploaded")
                        })
                    }
                    else{
                        print(error, terminator: "")
                    }
                })
            }
            else{
                print(error, terminator: "")
            }
        })
    }
```

I get this error:

> fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Failed to create PFFile at path
>   'file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/92BDA035-131C-4FD2-A176-25F77C1D295B/Documents/video.mp4':
>   file does not exist." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to
>   create PFFile at path
>   'file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/92BDA035-131C-4FD2-A176-25F77C1D295B/Documents/video.mp4':
>   file does not exist.}: file
>   /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-703.0.18.1/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift,
>   line 54

What is wrong? Why I get “file does not exist” when I successfully get the url from `println`? Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: Try `ls /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/92BDA035-131C-4FD2-A176-25F77C1D295B/Documents/video.mp4`

Comment: Does it work on the simulator?

Comment: @Jeef Does not work first link, and I can't in simulator, because I am using the phone camera to take a video and upload.

Comment: I'd guess its related to sandboxing -> probably need to give the app permission to access pictures and stuff.  Sorry cant help :(

Comment: @Jeef The app has permission to access pictures/photos, microphone, camera etc..

Answer (score 1):

Use `self.videoUrl.path` instead of `self.videoUrl.description` in your `try!` expression, as follows:

```
currentUploads["userFile"] = try! PFFile(name: "video.mp4", contentsAtPath: self.videoUrl.path)
```

(`videoUrl.description` is a string representation of the url, and has the scheme `"file://"` at the beginning, making it an invalid path.  In contrast, `videoUrl.path` is a string that begins with `"/var/mobile/..."`.)